# SQL: working with timestamped energy meter data

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with energy usage data in fifteen minute intervals:

| METER | TIMESTAMP | KWH |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2500396 | 12/04/2022 23:15 | 131.01 |
| 2500396 | 12/04/2022 23:30 | 132.11 |
| 2500396 | 12/04/2022 23:45 | 125.84 |
| 2500396 | 13/04/2022 00:00 | 127.27 |
| 2500396 | 13/04/2022 00:15 | 123.86 |
| 2500396 | 13/04/2022 00:30 | 114.51 |
| 2500396 | 13/04/2022 00:45 | 117.7 |
| 2500396 | 13/04/2022 01:00 | 120.01 |

I need to calculate energy usage per hour, where, for example, usage during hour 23 of 12/04/2022 is the sum of the intervals from **12/04/2022 23:15** to **13/04/2022 00:00** (notice the change in date), and usage during hour 0 of 12/04/2022 is the sum of the intervals from **13/04/2022 00:15** to **13/04/2022 01:00**.

I'll appreciate suggestions on how to code this concisely in Oracle SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can subtract 15 minutes from the times and then truncate to the start of the hour and then aggregate by that and the meter:

```sql
SELECT meter,
       TRUNC(timestamp - INTERVAL '15' MINUTE, 'HH') AS hour,
       SUM(kwh) AS total_kwh
FROM   table_name
GROUP BY
       meter,
       TRUNC(timestamp - INTERVAL '15' MINUTE, 'HH');
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (METER, TIMESTAMP, KWH) AS
SELECT 2500396, DATE '2022-04-12' + INTERVAL '23:15' HOUR TO MINUTE, 131.01 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2500396, DATE '2022-04-12' + INTERVAL '23:30' HOUR TO MINUTE, 132.11 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2500396, DATE '2022-04-12' + INTERVAL '23:45' HOUR TO MINUTE, 125.84 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2500396, DATE '2022-04-13' + INTERVAL '00:00' HOUR TO MINUTE, 127.27 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2500396, DATE '2022-04-13' + INTERVAL '00:15' HOUR TO MINUTE, 123.86 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2500396, DATE '2022-04-13' + INTERVAL '00:30' HOUR TO MINUTE, 114.51 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2500396, DATE '2022-04-13' + INTERVAL '00:45' HOUR TO MINUTE, 117.70 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2500396, DATE '2022-04-13' + INTERVAL '01:00' HOUR TO MINUTE, 120.01 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | METER | HOUR | TOTAL_KWH |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 2500396 | 2022-04-12 23:00:00 | 516.23 |
> | 2500396 | 2022-04-13 00:00:00 | 476.08 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=a800821f0c1fe438b6985e49cd225290)*

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But 2022-04-13 00:00:00 should be 2022-04-12 23h (hour 23 of 2022-04-12), and 2022-04-13 01:00:00 should be  2022-04-13 0h (hour 0 of  2022-04-13).

Comment: @oavaldezi Rather than adding 45 minutes, instead subtract 15.